# Swagger Jersey: How to specify boolean as response model

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui

One of my Jersey RestFull Service returns a boolean value, however I am unable to specify that in Swagger annotations.

```
@ApiResponses(value={
    @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Boolean true on success and boolean false otherwise", response=boolean.class)
})
```

I have tried both `Boolean.class` as well as `boolean.class` but no luck, On documentation page the "Response model" section is **empty**

Comment: What do you mean no luck? How does it manifest?

Comment: Fields like "HTTP Status Code" and "Reason " are populated correctly however It does not show on anything on swagger documentation page under "Response Model" heading.

Comment: That's due to a bug in swagger-ui. Don't look at what swagger-ui gives you, make sure the output in your swagger.json/yaml is right.